# How to integrate elasticsearch with Django

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am new to `elasticsearch`. I want to store my `MySQL Data` into `elasticsearch` for my `Django App`. But I have no idea where to start. I had a look at Haystack tutorial and I have indexed the data into the `elasticsearch` but how do I query that data?

models.py

```
import json
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


class scrapedData (models.Model):
    """ This a model for scraped data collected by eScraper"""

    productMRP = models.FloatField()                                      # Product MRP
    image_urls = models.TextField()                                       # Images URL's for image pipeline for downloading
    productSite = models.URLField()                                       # Product web-site URL
    productDesc = models.TextField()                                      # Product Description
    image_paths = models.TextField()                                      # Product images path on the local machine
    productImage = models.TextField()                                     # Product image URL's
    productTitle = models.TextField()                                     # Product title
    productPrice = models.FloatField()                                    # Product discounted price
    hasVariants = models.BooleanField()                                   # Product variants like : colors or sizes, True is if product has variants, False otherwise
    productCategory = models.TextField()                                  # Product category
    availability = models.BooleanField()                                  # Product availability ,True if product is in stock, False otherwise
    productSubCategory = models.TextField()                               # Product sub-category
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)                             # Product price currency
    productURL = models.URLField(max_length=500)                          # Product page URL
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                       # Time at which product is updated
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                   # Time at which product is created


class scrapedDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """scrapedData admin class"""

    list_display = ('productTitle','productSite','updatedAt','createdAt',
                    'product_URL','product_Image','productMRP','productPrice','currency',
                    'productDesc','productCategory','availability',
                    'hasVariants','productSubCategory','image_paths','image_urls'
                    )

    ordering = ('productSite',)


admin.site.register(scrapedData,scrapedDataAdmin)
```

seach_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from eScraperInterfaceApp.models import scrapedData

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class scrapedDataIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    """
        This is a index class for scrapedData model 
    """

    productMRP = indexes.CharField()
    productDesc = indexes.CharField()
    productTitle = indexes.CharField()
    productPrice = indexes.CharField()
    productCategory = indexes.CharField()
    productSubCategory = indexes.CharField()
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=False) # This field is the primary field for searching within

    def get_model(self):
        """
            This is a haystack method to get model name for the APP 
        """
        return scrapedData

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):        
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter()
```

Then I indexed the data into elasticsearch using : `python manage.py rebuild_index`

And when I tried:

```
from pprint import pprint 
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet


all_results = SearchQuerySet().all()
pprint(all_results)
```

And output was:

```
[
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'742')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'747')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'754')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'759')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'761')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'766')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'773')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'778')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'780')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'785')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'792')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'797')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'800')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'805')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'812')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'817')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'824')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'829')>,
    <SearchResult: eScraperInterfaceApp.scrapeddata (pk=u'831')>,
    '...(remaining elements truncated)...'
]
```

I want to use elasticsearch as a backend for my website. So I need to perform different type of query based on productDesc, MRP, price etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: What is the best way to do it haystack or something else....

Comment: can someone please tell me how to setup elastic search with Django

Comment: Hey @user2217267, I'm currently looking at this myself, not sure if you've already solved it, but from what I can see haystack is a pretty good approach... If your still stuck I'll answer the question after I've done my research :)...

Comment: Hey user2217267, Could you please post an answer to your own question if you've answered it? That would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SearchQuerySet().all()` is returning results, it seems like you're most of the way there. Now you just need to add a filter to get only the results you want.

Try this:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(title="AN EXISTING TITLE")
```

and see if you get a result with that title.

For more information, check the docs: [searchqueryset_api](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html).